# Why did a resazurin broth bottle turn pink immediately after being inoculated?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I have lawn cultures of aerobic bacteria kept at (2-8 °C), which I am trying to revive since they were kept longer than recommended. First, I tried to incubate a broth culture inoculated with a loopful from such cultures and then subculture the next day onto an agar medium. However, they showed no growth on the solid medium.

I resorted to another approach: I immersed a very heavy growth in a few mls of broth which was inoculated into manual blood culture bottles (rubber capped vials), as those:
[image]

Some of the bottles turned pink immediately after inoculation. Subsequently, I stained the immersion of these with simple stain (Safrinin), and it revealed the presence of the targeted organisms.

Is there any explanation for this other than that there were viable cells in the inoculum added to the blood culture bottles?

If there were viable cells, how come the color appeared too soon? Large number of viable cells maybe?

Did I push oxygen in with the inoculum through the syringe, so that the indicator got oxidized?

Comment: Some other manufacturers say this for the quality control part "color: Light straw coloured solution with upper 10% or less medium pink on standing", i saw some of the unused bottles have a slight pink color and I thought they were ill-manufactured. Maybe i should do a positive control and a real sterile control (inject sterile broth into a bottle, not just use a non used bottle), sorry I'm a dumb brick.

Comment: Definitely follow up with those controls, but very likely introduced oxygen when inoculating the tubes. Presumably there's oxygen in the broth and the syringe. I work with a lot of strict anaerobes, and I'm amazed at how sensitive resazurin indicator is. I can be pretty confident that my culture tubes were left open when cycling them into the anaerobic chamber, but sure enough there's always one or two where the anaerobe media goes pink as soon as I dispense it, just from that tiny bit of oxygenated atmosphere left in the tube.

Comment: @MikeyC they deleted my reply for unknown reasons. I wanted to say thank you and if this is not good to fit as an answer then what is!

Comment: Humble Mikey, i noticed that the "pink" i was refering to is the same color that appears when i injected mere air into a bottle, although i wasn't using aseptic manners, but if the indicator is too sensitive even to few oxygen, the few cells of air contaminants i might have introduced won't produce that few oxygen, right? Thanks.

Comment: i meant to say "..... when i injected intentionally mere air....."